# Indentify the plane defined by $Re(z\overline{z})=\frac{lm(\overline{z})}{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried:

$$Re(z\overline{z})=\frac{lm(\overline{z})}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\
Re((x+yi)(x-yi))=\frac{lm(x-yi)}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\
Re(x^2+y^2)= \frac{lm(x-yi)}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\
x^2 = \frac{-y}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\
-2x^2 = y$$

But my book states:

> Circunference of center $(0,-\frac{1}{4})$ and radius $\frac{1}{4}$.

What went wrong?

Comment: $\Re(x^2+y^2) = x^2+y^2$

Comment: @I.Padilla Why? I thought $\Re$ only considered the x coordinate. What happens exactly?

Comment: $x^2+y^2$ is a real number: $|z| = x^2+y^2+0i$ so $\Re (|z|) = x^2+y^2$. In other words, $x^2 + y^2$ is actually the "$x$" coordinate.

Comment: @I.Padilla In another exercise my book does this $\Re(2x)=2lm(x+yi) \Leftrightarrow 2x = 2y$. Why does it ignore the x?

Comment: FYI it's $\operatorname{Im}$ (as in **im**aginary), not $lm$.

Comment: @MarkRead Because the imaginary part $Im$ is signified by the $y$ because that carries the $i$, hence $2y$ in that example. But the term $x^2+y^2$ is a real number altogether. That's because the product of a complex number and its conjugate is real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Re(z\overline{z})=\frac{lm(\overline{z})}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\
Re((x+yi)(x-yi))=\frac{lm(x-yi)}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\
Re(x^2+y^2)= \frac{lm(x-yi)}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\
x^2 + y^2 = \frac{-y}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\
x^2 + (y+\frac{1}{4})^2 = \frac{1}{16}$$

Comment: Should be $y + 1/4$.

Comment: Should also be $=\frac{1}{4^2}$

Comment: Could you explain your last step? What did you do exatcly?

Comment: Sure: move $-y/2$ to the other side of the equation and complete the square by adding $1/16$ to both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$ then $z\bar{z} = (x^2 + y^2)  + 0i$ .

So $\Re(z\bar{z}) = x^2 + y^2$. Similarly $\bar{z} = x-iy$ so $\Im(\bar{z})=-y$. Hence the required plane is $$x^2 + y^2 = -\frac{y}{2} \iff x^2 + \left(y + \frac{1}{4}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$$ which is a circle centered at $(0, -1/4)$ and radius $1/4$.

---

Recall that whilst $\Re(z) = x$, it need not be the case that $\Re(z\bar{z}) = x^2$. In fact, if you let $z\bar{z} = u+iv$  you see that $u = x^2 + y^2$ and $v=0$. Then clearly $\Re(z\bar{z}) = u = x^2 + y^2$.